# Get one value from mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Do I have to put results from a query into an array if I know I'm only going to receive one password from the database? I'm using:

```
$sql = 'SELECT password FROM users WHERE userName="'.$username.'" LIMIT 1';
$result = $con->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
$hash = crypt($password,$row[0]);
if($row[0] == $hash){}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have stored hash in database (which you should) then you don't have to hash it again. also use prepared statement on user input.

```
$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT password FROM users WHERE userName=? LIMIT 1 ");
$sql->bind_param("s", $username);
$sql->execute();
$sql->bind_result($password_db);
while ($sql->fetch()) {

$hash = crypt($password,$password_db);
if($password_db == $hash){}

    }
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use `list` instead:

```
list($passwd) = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

if($passwd == $hash) {

};
```

Here's the [PHP reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

Comment: +1 This is as concise as you can get for retrieving a single value without a database abstraction library.

Answer (score 0):

Since $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM) is returning an array type, you could reference it directly:

if($result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)[0] == $hash) 
    ...